# Copy busy file from Samba share

Tags: ubuntu, backup, samba

I have an Ubuntu server which I use to backup from another server. I need to backup a file used by the other server, but without stopping it.

To connect the 2 servers, I use a Samba share. And to copy the file, I use `cp -f /mnt/remote/System.log /mnt/backup/today/System.log`. But when I run this command, I get this error:

```
cp: cannot open 'System.log' for reading: Device or resource busy
```

`lsof /mnt/remote` don't return anything.

How can I open (and copy) the file even if the device is busy, and without stopping the server...

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using rsync?

Comment: It don't work: `rsync: send_files failed to open "System.log": Device or resource busy (16)`